# Little error with an HTML forms and NodeJS

Tags: html, node.js, forms

I'm Hello everybody, i'm facing a small error right now I have two html form, and with nodeJS. And with POST request in NodeJS, it only goes to one of them no matter what.
Here is the code

```
<tr class="digitalLink"><td class="label">Input: Uncompressed GS1 Digital Link URI</td><td>

<form id="signUp"class="form-signUp" action="/compression" method="get" >
    <input id="uncompressedDigitalLinkInput" class="digitalLink" type="text" v-model="uncompressedDigitalLinkInput" name="compression"></td>

    <td class="charCount">{{uncompressedDigitalLinkInput.length}}</td>

    <button type="submit" form="signUp" style="margin-top:30px"
    class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" value="Compressed" >Compressed</button>
</form>
```

And The second forms :

```
<tr class="compressedDigitalLink"><td class="label">Input: Compressed GS1 Digital Link URI</td><td>
<form id="signUp"class="form-signUp" action="/decompression" method="post" >

<input id="compressedDigitalLinkInput2" class="compressedDigitalLink" type="text" v-model="compressedDigitalLinkInput2" name="decompression"></td>

<td class="charCount">{{compressedDigitalLinkInput2.length}}</td>

<button type="submit" form="signUp" style="margin-top:30px"
class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" value="Uncompressed" >Uncompressed</button>
```

And even if i click on the button of the second form i still have this error message
[image]

And here : the NodeJS code

```
    app.post('/decompression', function(req,resp){ //Post Response
  var decompression = req.body.decompression;
  console.log("Mon deuxieme test" + decompression);
});
```

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: I think, method for two forms should be `post` since you need to send data. And in nodeJS side. it should be app.post

Comment: I tried it but the error is still on @AjayVarghese

Comment: How are you running the app? Is it the same node process which is serving the UI ?

Comment: Yes i'm running with "node app.js"

Answer (score 1):

I think you have two problems here.

- `<button type="submit" form="signUp" style="margin-top:30px"
  class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" value="Uncompressed" >Uncompressed</button>`

   Both submit buttons point to the same form `id="signUp"`, which is the first form. Every HTML element should have a uniqueID, you need to specify different ID's to your form and reference them in your submit button (`form="signUp1", form="signUp2"`). Or preferably you can remove the form attribute in your submit button, since both submit buttons are in the their respective forms.
- `<form id="signUp"class="form-signUp" action="/decompression" method="post">`
  I don't think `action="/decompression"` is a valid way to reference your nodejs endpoint. On your local machine you may have `action="http://localhost:8080/decompression"`, the PORT may vary as your case may be. 
  Hope my answer is helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I just did what you told me by changing the id. What is weird is that when i remove the form attribute from the button, It doesn't work anymore. 

Anyway i still have the same error. Even when i clicked on the decompression part, i still have "cannot POST /decompression" @iodeveloper

Comment: Can you create a repo for your this project on github and share the link. I'll be glad to help.